# How do I run sed in TCL

Tags: string, sed, escaping, tcl, csh

I am trying to use TCLs builtin `exec` procedure to run the following `sed` shell command:

```
sed -i 's/"VALUE.${name}">.*</"VALUE.${name}">${value}</' ${dir}/imp.xml
```

However when I pass it to exec tcl errors out with

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

no idea how to interpret this.

I tried escaping the exec string:

```
exec {sed -i 's/"VALUE.${name}">.*</"VALUE.${name}">${value}</' ${dir}/imp.xml}
```

However this prevents the tcl variables from being expanded inside of the string.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get tcl to exec this sed program?

(my shell is csh if that is relevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution involved 2 changes to the command string,

1. Escape all the double quote characters, (thanks @Chris Heithoff)
2. Single quotes are handled funny by TCL, replacing them with double quotes
   (that are not escaped!) resolves the issue.

The final, working command string:

```
exec sed -i "s/\"VALUE.${name}\">.*</\"VALUE.${name}\">${alue}</" ${dir}/impl.xml
```

Comment: "Single quotes are handled funny by TCL" -- single quotes are not handled at all: they have no special meaning in Tcl. Tcl only has 12 syntax rules: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: At the csh command line, single quotes are used to prevent any wildcard globs or environment variables from getting expanded.   In this case, the Tcl interpreter is converting the ${name} and ${value} and ${dir} values to literal strings before sending the resulting string to the shell.    You're right that single quotes are not handled in Tcl, so they're sent to the sed command as literal single quotes, not single quotes for the shell to handle.

Comment: Tcl does not treat `'` in any special way at all; nothing in the language uses it to mean anything that I can think of. Instead, we use braces, which have the benefit of nesting and that turns out to almost always be what's wanted (nesting single quotes in shell is awful).

Answer (score 1):

Each argument to the `exec` command must correspond to an individual argument at the shell command line, so enclosing everything in {} doesn't work.

Try this:, where all double quotes and dollar signs are escaped.

```
exec sed -i 's/\"VALUE.\${name}\">.*</\"VALUE.\${name}\">\${value}' \${dir}/impl.xml
```

Comment: If I escape the dollar signs then the variables do not expand.
When I escape all of the double quote characters it errors out with:
```
invalid command name "sed"

sed -i 's/"VALUE.FUNCTION">.*</"VALUE.FUNCTION">69</' /home/guilty/proj...
```

Comment: Ok, I thought that the dollar signs literally were part of the .xml file to change.